# modifying classes in nokogiri with regex

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri to remove certain classes like so:

```
doc.css("span").remove_class("classname-1")
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove classes defined with regex. For instance, if I want to remove a class that has any series of numbers after it, like `/classname-\d+/`, how can I do that? It doesn't work by directly inserting the regex into the `remove_class` method, and I can't seem to find this question (or solution!) anywhere.

On a related note, would it also be possible to *search* for a class using regex, and then replace those classes with a single new class name?

Thank you for any insight/help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, with your current approach, I don't think you can do that with an existing method. But hey, when there is a will, there is a way! Have a look at `remove_class` [source](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb#L146-L160) :

```
  def remove_class name = nil
    each do |el|
      if name
        classes = el['class'].to_s.split(/\s+/)
        if classes.empty?
          el.delete 'class'
        else
          el['class'] = (classes - [name]).uniq.join " "
        end
      else
        el.delete "class"
      end
    end
    self
  end
```

Can you think of how you can make it work for your use case? The method above basically iterates over each `element` in the `NodeSet` you acquired from `doc.css('span')`, it gets the class of each of those element and see if it matches, if it does, it strips of that `class`.

Method can be patched like this:

```
module Nokogiri
  module XML
    class NodeSet
      def remove_class name = nil
        name = name.is_a?(String) ? Regexp.new("^#{name}$") : name
        each do |el|
          if name
            classes = el['class'].to_s.split(/\s+/)
            if classes.empty?
              el.delete 'class'
            else
              el['class'] = classes.reject{ |c| c.match name }.uniq.join " "
            end
          else
            el.delete "class"
          end
        end
        self
      end
    end
  end
end


doc.css('span').remove_class(/classname-1/) #=> Equivalent nodeset
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.css('span[class^="classname-"]').each{|el| el.delete 'class'}
```

is probably good enough, but if nbot maybe:

```
doc.css('span').select{|el| el[:class][/classname-\d/]}.each{|el| el.delete 'class'}
```